# Proposing the creation of an [auto-fill] tag for the CSS keyword

Tags: support, status-declined, tags, tag-creation-request

I would like to create the tag [auto-fill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto-fill), which would be for questions about the CSS grid/repeat function. This ("auto-fill") is a specific keyword in CSS, so I think it would be a useful tag.

However, when I tried to create this tag, the system said it was too similar to the existing [autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autofill) tag and refused to let me create it.

Is there a workaround for that? How can we create the tag?

Comment: Then disambiguate; I agree that [[tag:autofill]] and [[tag:auto-fill]] would be *far* too similar.

Comment: The `css-grid` tag should be more than specific enough.

Comment: Even if the [tag:css-grid] tag isn't sufficient, why create tags up that are so *obviously* going to be confusing such that the *system* tells you that they are too similar? Even *just in vanilla CSS*, there's at least two different uses of `auto-fill` (in some areas of `grid`) and `:autofill`, which is a CSS pseudo-class. So, even something like [tag:css-autofill] is *still* confusing. If you were really going to create tags for this, which doesn't seem to have the volume to justify it, then you should use something unambiguous like: [tag:css-grid-auto-fill] and [tag:css-selector-autofill].

Answer (score 20):

We don't need a tag for every CSS property, and we certainly don't need one for every *value* or *keyword* of every property; `auto-fill` is only one (partial) keyword of a single property in the CSS Grid layout module... it's unnecessary. As the comments above indicate, [css-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-grid) is plenty, here.